# Call mixin multiple times depending on option selected

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a mixin that looks like this:

```
mixin getrooms
  div
    label
    select
      - for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if i === 1
           option(value='#{i}') #{i} room
        else
           option(value='#{i}') #{i} rooms
      - }
+getrooms

mixin norooms
  div
    label Room Type:
    input(type='text', placeholder='Room Type', name='roomType')

+norooms
```

Depending on number of rooms selected id like to multiply the +norooms mixin.

Example if 3 were selected id like to display +norooms three times.

Any help would be really appreciated, not sure if the solution is with Pug or just pure Javascript but ill take any advice (just no jquery please).

I have a [pen](https://codepen.io/hamoodij/pen/zNMBQJ?editors=1100) that you can look at.

side note: when i try to console log the req.body.rooms it keeps returning #{i} rather than the actual textContent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not solvable with Pug, since it is non-static (Pug is only invoked once, before the HTML is sent to the client). Have a look at client-side event handling libraries, such as jQuery, which handle selection events. You can then multiply the item appropriately, e.g. with the [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

About your note: Attribute interpolation [is not supported anymore](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2346) in Pug. Simply say `value=id`.

Comment: I see, thank you for taking the time out to explain. Ill accept your answer :)